# How can i extract more than one key from an Object and print the output

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-hooks

How can i print more than one key from an object inside an event handler?

here is the link to my code - https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hamilton-erkqv

on line number 35 i call the event handler ChangeName with the object "x". I am able to print one key called 'name' (x.name)
How can i print all 3 props of the x object (name,id,type)??

tried to convert x into an array with object.keys(x) but when i loop through the output it gives an error saying cannot use map function

```
 const ChangeName = x => {
    setvalue(x.name);
  };


  <div>{value}</div> // display the results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your value is not an array its a object that why you can't use map method and this is how it works:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [posts, setposts] = useState([]);
  const [value, setvalue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const posts = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Name 1",
        type: "Type 1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Name 2",
        type: "Type 2"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Name 3",
        type: "Type 3"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Name 4",
        type: "Type 4"
      }
    ];

    setposts(posts);
  }, []);

  const ChangeName = x => {
    setvalue(x);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>
            {post.name},{post.type}
            <button onClick={() => ChangeName(post)}>More Info</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <div>
        {value.name}
        {value.id}
        {value.type}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Adel, this seems to work on the dummy code I created on the link shared above. But is giving me errors in my actual code .. difference is that actual code is pulling data from an API.. most part of the code is same. HEre is the error I am getting "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

A running code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [posts, setposts] = useState([]);
  const [values, setvalue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const posts = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Name 1",
        type: "Type 1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Name 2",
        type: "Type 2"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Name 3",
        type: "Type 3"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Name 4",
        type: "Type 4"
      }
    ];

    setposts(posts);
  }, []);

  const ChangeName = x => {
    console.log(Object.values(x));
    Object.values(x).map(k => setvalue(k));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>
            {post.name},{post.type}
            <button onClick={ChangeName.bind(this, post)}>More Info</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <div>{values}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**You need to set values not value.**